# How to List Tables from current map document (mxd)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

We have many maps containing Feature Classes and Tables in a Personal Geodatabase that need their information updated.

Is there a function to List Tables from the current map document like

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
```

in ArcGIS 10.1?

Answer (score 8):

It's [`arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//00s300000006000000) that you need to use to get a handle on tables in a map document.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
for table in arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd):
    print "Table {0}: {1}".format(table.name, table.dataSource)
```

Comment: if tables add in the mxd it will give list but in this case only FeatureClass added in the mxd.

Comment: Your question was "Is there a function to List Tables from the current map document", well thats what ListTableView() does, so I'm not sure what you are saying?

Comment: The current mxd contains FeatureClasses only but need to get/open tables because excel sheet name either matching with FeatureClass/Table, accordingly attribute will update.

Comment: Excel spreadsheets are read only in ArcMap, so if you did load them you would not be able to update them from within ArcMap, unless you intend to join the Excel table to a FeatureClass and pass over some sort of attribute from the Excel file?

Comment: The objective is to update excel to gdb and our script is working on FeatureClass without any issue. At present little progress in the code that we taken Layer.workspacepath and set the arcpy.env.workspace then it return listtables. Is this way correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look at listing data using arcpy.

[Listing Tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000002t000000) - Lists the tables in the workspace, limited by name and table type.

[Listing Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListFeatureClasses/018v00000018000000/) - Lists the feature classes in the workspace, limited by name, feature type, and optional feature dataset.

[Listing Files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListFiles/018v0000000v000000/) - Returns a list of files in the current workspace based on a query string. Specifying search conditions can be used to limit the results.

You might have to iterate on each workspace source in your MXD.

Comment: nothing return >>> arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>>> tables = arcpy.ListTables()
>>> print tables
[]

Comment: @user24443: So does it work or not? Or do you also need help on how to print the items in the `tables` array?

Comment: It is not working. We need to get tables and loop where excel sheet name is matching with table name then update field attribute. The mxd contains only featureclasses but tables are not.